# How do I stop ReSharper/Rider from doing this: "}, {"

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting, rider, jetbrains-rider

How do I prevent rider from generating `}, {` between chopped elements of an initialization?
I looked through `Editor --> Code Style --> Braces Layout/Line Breaks and Wrapping`, but I may have missed something. Surely this mildly weird construction is not forced upon us?

What Rider does:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> rider = new() {
{
    "first", new[] {
        "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "e", "f"
    }
}, { // <-- Not desired
    "first", new[] {
        "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "e", "f"
    }
};
```

Preferred:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> rider = new() {
{
    "first", new[] {
        "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "e", "f"
    }
},
{   // <-- Want this
    "first", new[] {
        "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "e", "f"
    }
};
```

My current settings may be wrong:
[image: Line Breaks and Wrapping]

[image: Braces Layout]

Comment: You are missing a closing brace on your example.

Comment: You are correct, but the original question applies. I should have tested my example in LINQPad before posting, but it was more of a quick "I need to make an example" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *Expressions (initializers, switch expressions, patterns)* to *At next line (BSD style)*:
[image]